# Apache Beam pass list as argument - Python SDK

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have an Apache Beam pipeline which would take a list as arguments and use it in the Filter and Map function. Since these would be available as string I had converted using ast.literal_eval on them. Is there any other better way to do the same thing?

```
import argparse
import ast
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions

def run_pipeline(custom_args, beam_args):
    elements = [
     {'name': 'Jim', 'join_year': 2010, 'location': 'LA', 'role': 'Executive assistant'},
     {'name': 'Tim', 'join_year': 2015, 'location': 'NY', 'role': 'Account manager'},
     {'name': 'John', 'join_year': 2010, 'location': 'LA', 'role': 'Customer service representative'},
     {'name': 'Bob', 'join_year': 2020, 'location': 'NJ', 'role': 'Customer service representative'},
     {'name': 'Michael', 'join_year': 2019, 'location': 'CA', 'role': 'Scheduler'},
     {'name': 'Adam', 'join_year': 2010, 'location': 'CA', 'role': 'Customer service representative'},
     {'name': 'Andrew', 'join_year': 2009, 'location': 'TX', 'role': 'Account manager'},
     {'name': 'James', 'join_year': 2017, 'location': 'NJ', 'role': 'Executive assistant'},
     {'name': 'Paul', 'join_year': 2015, 'location': 'NY', 'role': 'Scheduler'},
     {'name': 'Justin', 'join_year': 2015, 'location': 'NJ', 'role': 'Scheduler'}
     ]

    opts = PipelineOptions(beam_args)
    joinYear = [i for i in ast.literal_eval(custom_args.joinYear)]
    selectCols = [i for i in ast.literal_eval(custom_args.selectCols)]

    with beam.Pipeline(options=opts) as p:
        (p 
        | "Create" >> beam.Create(elements) 
        | "Filter for join year in 2010 and 2015" >> beam.Filter(lambda item: item['join_year'] in joinYear) 
        | "Select name and location columns" >> beam.Map(lambda line : {key:value for (key,value) in line.items() if key in selectCols})
        | beam.Map(print)
        )


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--joinYear",required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--selectCols",required=True)


    my_args, beam_args = parser.parse_known_args()
    run_pipeline(my_args, beam_args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I run the code above like this `python filterlist.py --joinYear='[2010,2015]' --selectCols="['name','location']"`

In actual production use I would pass these parameters from a Cloud Function and launch the dataflow job. So was wondering if there is any other better way to do the same following better practise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't directly pass a `Python` list as program argument.

You are in the good direction with your choice and your implementation.

If you need to pass structure like `List`, `Dict`, `List of Dict`, you need to pass it as `String` in the pipeline option. Then in the job, transform this `String` to the expected structure.

It is a kind of serialization(String)/deserialization(Object).

If you pass by a `Cloud Function` or another process, you can format and apply the serialization programmatically in your code, for the option.

For example for a `Dict` or a `List of Dict`, you can use :

- `json.dumps` for serialization
- `json.loads` for deserialization

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Since the Cloud Function is in Go, instead of doing the serialisation I just passed the list as string and did json.loads in the dataflow job. And also I think it should be `json.dumps()` instead of `json.dump()` since `json.dump()` expects a file.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes you are right, it's `json.dumps`, I edited my answer :)